# Comparison of array with variable

Tags: arrays

I want to compare normal variable with the array one. I used the following code:

```
$child_ids[0]=0;
$c=array($child_ids[$get_children->tid]);
if(isset($_GET['tid'])==$c)
{
  //code
}
```

Can anyone please tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: First, what language is that, PHP? Use tags! And second, how do you imagine a comparison between a scalar and an array? Is `[1, 2]` equal to `1`, `2`, or `3`?

Comment: Please add extra infos, like describing what you're trying to achieve and which errors you get. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: be aware, that `isset()` returns true or false, you have to do the check beforehand! then use `in_array()` as Jakir suggested

Comment: @Dmitry yes php, I included both tags , and yes I want to compare just as you mention in your comment

Comment: @hexerei software, I took the value of `isset($_GET['tid']` in a variable too

Comment: @ Phate01, in my question `$get_children` contains different variety of data of different objects like name, tid etc

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in_array( $_GET['tid'] , $c) )
{
  //code
}
```

Comment: Thanku @jakir but didnt work, in my question `$get_children` contains different variety of data of different objects like name, tid etc

Comment: Can you add some reference to the PHP manual, and some short explanation?